# Figma's "Change To" not working well with elements using "Fix position when scrolling"

Tags: figma, prototyping

I've started using Figma's beta "Change to" feature and it's amazing but I just noticed that when using it on elements that have fixed positioning while scrolling, it's not working as expected. It works perfectly before beginning the scroll (see beginning part of linked video below). But then after scrolling and initiating the change to on hover, it seems to go away and then appear, creating a distracting blinking effect (you can see this in the second part of the linked video below). And if I scroll almost all the way back to the top of the page and try again, you can see the element that it's changing to appears to be wanting to start from y:0 instead of the current scroll position (you can see this in the last part of the linked video below). Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vd42s8h9jl3p0op/Issue-with-Change-To-and-Fixed-Positioning.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Ask Figma - it's a beta.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a good next step but just thought I could maybe get quicker input here from people already using that feature.